# How to sort a dictionary in descending order according its value?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
orders = {
    'apple: 54,
    'banana': 56,
    'orange': 72,
    'peach': 48,
    'grape': 41
}
```

Given a dictionary in this format, how can I sort the dictionary in descending order by values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sort_orders = sorted(orders.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: Please read [answer] there is absolutely no effort made on this answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sorted function to do it.

```py
orders = {
    'apple': 54,
    'banana': 56,
    'orange': 72,
    'peach': 48,
    'grape': 41
}

d = sorted(orders.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
print(dict(d))
```

**output:**

> {'orange': 72, 'banana': 56, 'apple': 54, 'peach': 48, 'grape': 41}

Comment: print (type((sorted))) gives you list, not a dict

Comment: Please don't answer questions when it is a clear duplicate. It just encourages people to not make an effort to research the question and use existing resources. We all like to help but it just encourages the wrong activity.